# How can I pass a data from one form to another when both are on the same component?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, components, angular-forms

So I have a sale window that contains two forms, one is tied to the table sale and the other to the table `saleItem`, the problem is that `saleItem` needs to be tied by id to a sale, so how can I pass the value of the id from the sale form that I'm creating to the `saleItem` form?

sale-item-cad.html:

```html
<form [formGroup]="formGroupSale">
    <div class="forms-field-top">
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Vendedor:</mat-label>
            <input id="nameEmployee" matInput formControlName="id_employee" [matAutocomplete]="autoEmployee">
            <mat-autocomplete #autoEmployee="matAutocomplete">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let employee of employees" [value]="employee.id">{{employee.id}} - {{employee.name}}</mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Filial:</mat-label>
            <input matInput formControlName="id_branch" [matAutocomplete]="autoBranch">
            <mat-autocomplete #autoBranch="matAutocomplete">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let branch of branches" [value]="branch.id">{{branch.id}} - {{branch.name}}</mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Cliente:</mat-label>
            <input matInput formControlName="id_customer" [matAutocomplete]="autoCustomer">
            <mat-autocomplete #autoCustomer="matAutocomplete">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let customer of customers" [value]="customer.id">{{customer.id}} - {{customer.name}}</mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <div class="form-fields-bottom">
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Produto:</mat-label>
            <input matInput formControlName="id_product" [matAutocomplete]="autoProduct" placeholder="Nome do produto - Valor">
            <mat-autocomplete #autoProduct="matAutocomplete">
                <mat-option  *ngFor="let product of products" [value]="product.id">{{product.id}} - {{product.name}} {{product.id}} - {{product.sale_price}}</mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Valor de  venda:</mat-label>
            <input matInput>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Quantidade:</mat-label>
            <input matInput formControlName="quantity">
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div class="form-fields-bottom">
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Forma de pagamento:</mat-label>
            <mat-select [(value)]="paymentModel">
                <mat-option value="A vísta">
                    A vísta
                </mat-option>
                <mat-option value="Crédito">
                    Crédito
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field  *ngIf="paymentModel == 'Crédito'">
            <mat-label>Prestações:</mat-label>
            <mat-select>
                <mat-option value="1x">
                    1x
                </mat-option>
                <mat-option value="2x">
                    2x
                </mat-option>
                <mat-option value="3x">
                    3x
                </mat-option>
                <mat-option value="4x">
                    4x
                </mat-option>
                <mat-option value="5x">
                    5x
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</form>
</form>
<div>
    <button (click)="saveOrUpdate()">Submit</button>
</div>
<!--<div>-->
<!--    <h3>Resumo da Operação:</h3>-->
<!--    <p>Vendedor responsável: <span [innerHTML]="nameEmployee"></span></p>-->
<!--</div>-->
```

sale-item-cad.ts:

```
import {Component, Injector} from '@angular/core';
import {BaseComponentDirective} from "../../base-component.directive";
import {SaleItemComponent} from "../sale-item.component";
import {BaseService} from "../../../services/base.service";
import {Product} from "../../../models/product";
import {URLS} from "../../app.urls";
import {SaleItem} from "../../../models/sale-item";
import {FormGroup} from "@angular/forms";
import {Employee} from "../../../models/employee";
import {Branch} from "../../../models/branch";
import {Customer} from "../../../models/customer";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sale-item-cad',
  templateUrl: './sale-item-cad.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sale-item-cad.component.scss']
})
export class SaleItemCadComponent extends BaseComponentDirective<SaleItemComponent>{

    public products: Product[] = [];
    public employees: Employee[] = [];
    public branches: Branch[] = [];
    public customers: Customer[] = [];
    public productService: BaseService<Product>;
    public employeeService: BaseService<Employee>
    public branchService: BaseService<Branch>
    public customerService: BaseService<Customer>
    public object = new SaleItem();
    public formGroupSale: FormGroup;
    public paymentModel: any;
  constructor(public injector: Injector) {
    super(injector, {pk:"id",endpoint: URLS.SALE_ITEM, retrieveOnInit: true});
    this.productService = this.createService(Product, URLS.PRODUCT);
    this.employeeService = this.createService(Employee, URLS.EMPLOYEE);
    this.branchService = this.createService(Branch, URLS.BRANCH);
    this.customerService = this.createService(Customer, URLS.CUSTOMER);
  }

  createFormGroup(): void {
    this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
        id: [null],
        quantity: [null],
        id_product: [null],
        id_sale: [this.formGroupSale],
        active: true,
        created_at: new Date()

    });
    this.formGroupSale = this.formBuilder.group({
        id: [null],
        date: new Date(),
        id_branch: [null],
        id_customer:[null],
        id_employee: [null],
        active: true,
        created_at: new Date()
    })
  }


    ngOnInit(callback?: () => void) {
        super.ngOnInit(() => {
            this.loadEmployees(),
                this.loadBranches(),
                this.loadProducts(),
                this.loadCustomers()
        })
    }

    loadProducts(): void {
      this.productService.getAll().subscribe(
          (res: Product[]) => {
            this.products = res;
          },
          (error: any) => {
            console.error(error);
          }
      );
    }
    loadEmployees(): void {
        this.employeeService.getAll().subscribe(
            (res: Employee[]) => {
                this.employees = res;
            },
            (error: any) => {
                console.error(error);
            }
        );
    }

    loadBranches(): void {
        this.branchService.getAll().subscribe(
            (res: Branch[]) => {
                this.branches = res;
            },
            (error: any) => {
                console.error(error);
            }
        );
    }
    loadCustomers(): void {
        this.customerService.getAll().subscribe(
            (res: Customer[]) => {
                this.customers = res;
            },
            (error: any) => {
                console.error(error);
            }
        );
    }

    saveOrUpdate(callback?: (event: number) => void) {
        console.log(this.formGroup.value);
        console.log(this.formGroupSale.value);
        super.saveOrUpdate(callback);
    };

}
```

I've tried some solutions given by the (almost) all-knowing chatGPT but no success.

Comment: Would it make sense to actually make this two different components? At first glance, it looks like the one component is doing too much. Each component should have a single responsibility. Another option would be to use a service to store the "current item".